# Ext4 Component Show

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework

Please be gentile I am in the process of learning Ext4.

When I run the code below I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCount' of undefined`. When I comment out the code: `list.show()` in NS.view.ImplementationStatus.Legend the error goes away. So I think it has something to do with this but I don't really understand where this would come from.

```
Ext.define('NS.controller.ImplementationStatuses', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['ImplementationStatuses'],
    models: ['ImplementationStatus'],
    views: ['ImplementationStatus.Legend'],
    init: function() {
        var view = Ext.widget('statusLegend');
    }
});

Ext.define('NS.view.ImplementationStatus.Legend', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.statusLegend',
    views: ['ImplementationStatus.List'],
    initComponent: function() {
        console.log("Initializing NS.view.ImplementationStatus.Legend");

        // This creates the list of statuses
        var list = Ext.create('NS.view.ImplementationStatus.List', {});
        list.show();

        // Define the list of items
        this.items = [list];
    }
});

Ext.define('NS.view.ImplementationStatus.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.statusList',
    initComponent: function() {
        console.log("Initializing NS.view.ImplementationStatus.List");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of extending Ext Component classes is to use initComponent function like you are using, but at the end you need to call `this.callParent(arguments);`

You can see this pattern used throughout all views in the guides: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: I think you are right. The other way seems to be the ExtJS 3.x way. And since I did say it was for ExtJS 4.x I'm going to give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you create overrides for methods like init, initComponent, you must also call method from original class. For example:

```
Ext.window.Window.prototype.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
```

After completing methods the error is not showing anymore.

Comment: I think this is the 3x way of doing things. Please see my answer below for newer recommended approach.